# For what initial conditions $y_0=y(-1)$ the solution of ODE $\dot y=-2ty^{2}$ is defined for all time?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $\frac{dy}{dt}=-2ty^{2}$ with $y(-1)=y_0$ then using the old trick that if $y\not=0$ then $-\frac{\dot y}{y^2}=2t$, integrate in $t_{0}=-1$ to $t$ we have:
$$\int_{-1}^{t}-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{ds}ds=\int_{-1}^{t}2sds=t^2-1,$$
and 
$$\int_{-1}^{t}-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{ds}ds=\int_{-1}^{t}\frac{d}{ds}\big(\frac{1}{y}\big)ds=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}.$$
Then $\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}=t^2-1$ and finally $$y(t)=\frac{1}{(t^2-1)+1/y_0}.$$ The solution $y(t)$ is defined for all time if $y_0(t^2-1)+1\not=0$, if $y_0(t^2-1)+1=0$ therefore $1/y_0=1-t^2$.

I don't understand what it mean, $y_0$ depends of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have

$$ y(t) = \frac{1}{t^2-1+1/y_0}.$$

Check the denominator : $ t^2-1+1/y_0 $ have solution in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $1 - 1/y_0 \geqslant 0$, i.e. $y_0 \geqslant 1$ or $y_0 < 0$. If $y_0 \geqslant 1$ or $y_0 < 0$, let $t_0 = -\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{y_0}}$. When $t$ moves from $-1$ to $t_0$, the value of $y$ tends to $+\infty$. So $y$ cannot be defined as a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.

On the contrary, if $0 < y_0 < 1$, then the value of  $ y(t) = \frac{1}{t^2-1+1/y_0}$ would always be between $0$ and $ \frac{y_0}{1 - y_0}$, thus $y$ is a bounded smooth function defined on$\mathbb{R}$.